# How to reduce too much space between two columns with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is too much space between two form-groups, if i reduce the column size of the first one it goes on next line which i don't want. I would like email address to be closer to phone extension. Is there any way to do this without moving email address field with css left margins?

[image]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <label for="telephoneNumber">Telephone Number</label>
            <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber1" maxlength="3" size="3">-
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber2" maxlength="3" size="3">-
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber3" maxlength="3" size="3">Ext
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension" maxlength="3" size="3">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of columns on a row is equal to 12.

You have set the class `.col-md-5` on your first column which means it would take about 50% of the available width. And your next column starts immediately after that.
A solution would be to set a class with fewer column on your first form-group, let's say `col-md-3`. Here's a demo: http://output.jsbin.com/tipusi/1/

Comment: I agree.  It looks like your first column is wider than the content that fills it.  Bootstrap columns have padding placed in between them by default, so only use as many columns as you need.  You can remove the padding via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <div class="inline-block">
          <label for="telephoneNumber">Telephone Number</label>
              <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber1" maxlength="3" size="3">-
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber2" maxlength="3" size="3">-
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber3" maxlength="3" size="3">Ext
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension" maxlength="3" size="3">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="inline-block">
          <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS-->
.inline-block {display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5 no-padding">
        <label for="telephoneNumber">Telephone Number</label>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber1" maxlength="3" size="3">-
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber2" maxlength="3" size="3">-
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telephoneNumber3" maxlength="3" size="3">Ext
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="extension" maxlength="3" size="3">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 no-padding">
        <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailAddress">
    </div>
</div>
```

Add below css class

```
.less-padding {
   padding: 10px !important;
   margin: 10px !important;
}
.no-padding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```